# How to close two tabs and open a new tab with different url

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I have a test case in QA where guest clicks on a link and a new tab will opens. But this new tab is defaulting to Prod, so I don't want to continue my test case in prod and I want this tab to close and navigate to a different url (the one that pointing to QA). How I can implement this using selenium web driver?

Comment: getAction().click(BeautySalonLocators.BOOK_APPOINTMENT_LINK);
        HashMap<String, String> childWindowhandle = new HashMap<>();
        getWaits().waitForWindowToBeVisible(2, 60);
        childWindowhandle = getAction().getWindowHandles();
        getAction().switchToWindow(childWindowhandle, "CHILD");
        getAction().goToURL(Constants.SALON_URL); // this is used to navigate to the services booking page URL
        return this;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clicking the link you can save it's href attribute and let the driver load url you want. Or you can switch between tabs. Following code should help you.

```
package links;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Links {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // init driver
        String chromeDriverPath = "C:\\Users\\pavel.burgr\\Desktop\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // get EN page
        driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink");
        waitSec(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("p-logo")));
        WebElement hyperlinked = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/wiki/Hyperlinked')]"));

        // get the href attribute of webelement 'Hyperlinked'
        String href = hyperlinked.getAttribute("href");

        // change the href
        String alteredHref = href.replace(".en", ".cs");

        // open new Tab
        openAndGoToNewTab(driver);

        // load page with altered url (czech version of the same page)
        driver.get(alteredHref);
        waitSec(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("p-logo")));
    }

    // custom wait method
    public static WebDriverWait waitSec(WebDriver driver, int sec) {
        return new WebDriverWait(driver, sec);
    }


    // opens new tab and switch to it
    public static void openAndGoToNewTab(WebDriver driver) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.open()");
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabs.size() - 1));
    }

    // close current tab
    public static void closeTab(WebDriver driver) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("window.close()");
    }

    // switch to tab by index
    public static void swotchToTab(WebDriver driver, int tabIndex) {
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(tabIndex));
    }
}
```

Comment: getAction().click(BeautySalonLocators.BOOK_APPOINTMENT_LINK);
        HashMap<String, String> childWindowhandle = new HashMap<>();
        getWaits().waitForWindowToBeVisible(2, 60);
        childWindowhandle = getAction().getWindowHandles();
        getAction().switchToWindow(childWindowhandle, "CHILD");
        getAction().goToURL(Constants.SALON_URL); // this is used to navigate to the services booking page URL
        return this;